# 3**2+1!=30/3 it gives False

Tags: python-3.x

```
3**2+1!=30/3
```

it gives False..why?? it should be True

```
3**2+1!=30//3(also False which is right)
```

Behavior of decimal divide operator and floating divide operator in operator assignment python3

Comment: They have the same numeric value, so why _wouldn't_ they compare the same?

Comment: 9+1==10 or what am I missing?

Comment: Are you confusing 1 factorial equals and 1 not equals (i.e. `1!  =` vs `1 !=`)? In python equals to comparisons use a double `==`. This means `3**2+1!=30/3` reads as '10 not equal to 10' which is False. I think you perhaps mean `(3**2 + math.factorial(1)) == 30/3`. NB: I am aware that 1! is 1 - I just kept it for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

both sides evaluate to 10, 10!=10 is False (it is False that 10 does not equal 10 since 10 does in fact equal 10)

/ does integer division if both inputs are integers. In this case, they both are, so it is equivalent to //